# In Clonezilla - what is the "-fsck-src-part-y" option used for? Is it safe to use it?

Tags: command-line, fsck, clonezilla

What is the

```
-fsck-src-part-y
```

option when running Clonezilla?--I'm trying to back up a USB stick with 5 partitions to another USB stick as a file and I'm getting `Failed to save partition /dev/sde5`. **Is it safe** to use the `-fsck-src-part-y` option with "**Auto (Caution!) check and repair source file system before saving**", as the `-sfck` option is failing to process the last (/dev/sde5) partition?

Comment: Which means running fsck -f -y on source partition

Comment: @AlvinLiang: That I know. My question is if it's safe to run in `-fsck-src-part-y` **mode**, since running Clonezilla in `-sfck` mode returned with **error messages**, among others saying **Failed to save partition /dev/sde5**